# simple regular expression question

Tags: regex, unix, yacc, lex

How to match aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab where number of a's should be min of 10?

I mean i know this way:

```
[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]a*b
```

But there must be a better elegant method where is if my min number of a's become say 100..

What is it? I am trying to match (a^n)b sort of thing where n can be anything

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention this is done using lex and yacc.. where the lex has to return a token to yacc.

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
aaaaaaaaaa[a]*b {return ok;}
\n {return '\n';}
. {return 0;}
%%
```

Comment: are you using perl syntax for you regex?

Comment: I am doing this using lex and yacc in knoppix 4.0 as a programing practice exercise ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `lex` is [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html), you can use `a{10,}`.

If not so, according to
[3. Lex Regular Expressions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html)
, you can use `a{10}a*` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
a{10,}
```

which says `a` 10 or more times.

```
grep -E "a{10,}" filename
```

matches `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab` but not `aaaaaaaaab`.

Answer (score 1):

Footy,

**[WARNING: This answer is COMPLETE BUNKUM!!!]**

(if you mean soccer, we're swarn enemies ;-)

Ummm, **No**... That is not as far as I know, using "the standard" regular expression syntax as supported by sed, grep, nawk, and the likes... and no not even egrep... As far as I know, the `a{10,*}` syntax (which is exactly what you're hankering for) didn't emerge until Perl rewrote all the books on the capabilities of regular expressions... and (don't quote me on this) I don't think that happened until like version 5.

So yeah, If you're stuck with using nawk, then it's the aaaaaaaaardvarking hardway dude. Sorry.

Cheers. Keith.

---

**EDIT:**

Hmmm... I seem to be the odd-man-out here... maybe everone-elses "standard operating environment(s)" have been updated with "standard tools" that recognise later regular expression syntax extensions... Sooo... Hmmm... I tested this on my (three year old) **cygwin** implementation of **egrep**... and it suprised me by actually working!!!

```
Administrator@snadbox3 ~
$ egrep 'a{3,}b' <<-eof
> ab
> aab
> aaab
> aaaab
> eof
aaab
aaaab
```

So **I'm WRONG** all ends up... looks like the "new" `{min,[max]}` syntax is reasonably well supported, and I'm getting old. Sigh.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: yep i mean soccer only ! :D And i am using lex and yacc here to solve this problem... but the method you said gave unrecognized rule error in knnopix 4.0

Answer (score -1):

use this format : `a^na*b` and replace n with any number you want.

Comment: No bananas for me: `$ egrep 'a^3a*b' <<-eof
 > ab
 > aab
 > aaab
 > aaaab
 > eof`